# The Cutoff frequency of bandpass filter

Tags: filter, active-filter, bode-plot, cutoff-frequency, band-pass

Given:

1. Center Frequency f0 = 2.2KHz
2. Q factor = 5

**The problem** I'm facing is this: How do I calculate the 2 cutoff frequencies of this band pass filter? I'm confused because my question says "The cutoff frequency is not always the -3dB point. This is only the case for Q = 0.707".

I found a website that calculates the cutoff for a band pass, and the results were:

**[F1 = 20KHz to F2= 2.4KHz].**

But when I simulate the circuit in Multisim, I have a huge difference between the results:

**[F1= 1kHz and F2=5kHz].**

I need a way to calculate the two cutoff frequencies. The **system functions** are given at the end of the figures:

[image]

[image]

Copied from Wikipedia!

[image]

Comment: "I'm confused because my question says "The cutoff frequency is not always the -3dB point." Are you sure that this statemenet was used in conjunction with your bandpass? I think, it applies - in particular - to LOWPASS stages.

Answer (score 1):

The results Multisim gives you are correct. You can check it by using [this calculator](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Center-frequency-calculator.php).

The cutoff frequencies are calculated by analyzing the circuit and seeing which part of it is responsible for low-/high-pass and calculating the corresponding frequencies. Check out [this website](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/second-order-filters.html) for a detailed explanation!

As to the results you got from a website, they seem to be wrong or misinterpreted - your center frequency is only 2.2 kHz, but f1 is 20 kHz and f2 is 2.4 kHz - the range doesn't even cover the center frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The Q is always defined as \$Q=f_O/\Delta f_{-3dB}\$

> The cutoff frequencies are **always** the -3dB point or voltage = 0.707 compared to peak=1

The \$|f2-f1|=\Delta f\$. which are the -3dB values.

Δf = BW\$_{ −3dB}\$ or the half-power full bandwidth

For more detail on a recent question (Oct 2021).
[Creating a digital PLL](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/589556/creating-a-digital-pll#589556)

Comment: Would you call \$\Delta f \$ for the "bandwidth" @Tony?

Comment: @Carl  yes that is Δf.=BW \$_{-3dB}\$ or the half-power full bandwidth