# Creating a digital PLL

Tags: fpga, pll, digital-filter

I want to drive a quartz crystal resonator at its resonant frequency so I need to stay locked on to its resonant frequency as its resonant frequency changes. I'm using an FPGA to do this.

I want to use a PLL to stay locked on to the resonant frequency. My quandary is, **how do I capture and compare the phase shift that occurs when the resonant frequency changes?**

Suppose my setup is like this:
[image]

A normal PLL loop looks like this:
[image]

I would assume that in the typical PLL loop, my "VCO" is the DDS (since the frequency output of the DDS is determined by a constant value input just like a DC signal controls an AC output of a VCO) and the "reference signal" would be the response signal of the resonator (ie. the desired frequency).

Now suppose at time = 0 I know what the resonant frequency is (maybe I found it by doing a frequency sweep and looking for amplitude response). Then, some time later, the resonant frequency changes.

The "new" resonant frequency would cause the "old" frequency to phase shift. **But how would I quantify this?**

Typical methods involve comparing the signals in the time domain which would mean I would somehow need to save one period of the "old" frequency I'm driving the resonator at and then "overlay" that with the correct period in time with the "new" phase shifted signal such that the phase difference is apparent (they must be synchronized).

My design would look like this:

[image]

This seems very convoluted and I believe I'm overcomplicating things.

Comment: Yes you are ...  You need to define your resonator transfer function as either series or parallel and simply make it oscillate satisfying the Barkhausen criterion.

Comment: If you are able to detect the resonant frequency during a sweep using peak amplitude, maybe you can just keep sweeping the frequency (slowly) up and down to stay right near the peak as the peak moves. If the amplitude is increasing as you sweep, keep sweeping. If the amplitude is getting smaller, sweep in the other direction. Obviously this would cause it to hunt back and forth near the peak which might not be desireable. And it might not work if the resonant frequency changes very rapidly.

Comment: Doesn’t Barkhausen stability criterion apply to oscillators? My understanding is that a DC voltage applied to an oscillator alters it’s frequency. In this case, my VCO would be the DDS (not the resonator itself) and it’s “DC” signal would be the controlling value that determines the frequency of the DDS’s outputted signal. Is this analysis correct?

Comment: @mikeith Yes, that is the problem. I can’t test in the proximity of the resonant frequency because the Quality factor is so huge that small changes in resonant frequency mean a completely flatline amplitude response which leaves me at a loss for where resonance is. I need to watch phase to know what direction the frequency went and “how far”

Comment: You have a resonator.  Why can't you let it hunt for it's own frequency and then just measure it?  A Pierce oscillator is easy to implement even with an FPGA and then you can just measure the frequency.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator

Comment: @AndrewLentvorski  The model of the Pierce osc was OK for 4000 series CMOS and  similar gain GBW limited designs suitable for many resonators, but the impedance and osc mode needs  to be chosen 1st then choose the RdsOn and gm or Av of the amplifier to make it work.  Many Inverters are buffered and uncompensated but have natural Miller Capacitance may resonate at a zero or pole in the oscillator or not at all. But conceptually , you have the right idea.  Make it oscillate series or // by design.

Comment: You also need to decide if you want the current response or the voltage response relative to the pulse exciter. It makes a difference, as I answered.  **What is the resonator? and do you know its polar impedance? or orthogonal response with Bode Gain + phase response?**  This matters!

Comment: It’s a quartz crystal resonator

Comment: @Andrew are you serious. That's all you can say for specs?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yes. Anything else I need to know I will probably have to experimentally determine. It is literally a 1955 Soviet resonator used for communication. I can ask my professor if he knows about the neighborhood of the specs but I'm mostly using this for a proof of concept. I don't need a high performance resonant lock at this stage. Its fundamental series resonance is ~6.4 MHz

Comment: -1 for a poorly defined question.  Next time show what you have and what you need for an input and output rather than your suggested overthinking solution.  This way  , wasted too much time.

Comment: Are you looking for an LO sine wave? or a square wave? or a fractional N synth with a frequency counter/synth or what?   Come on @Andrew define the requirements, not an overly complicated question steering in the wrong direction.  Do you want 20 ppm over the whole temp and supply range or 2 ppm or 0.1 ppm or just activate an old Russian radio? or synchronize a 6MHz clock referenced to a 10 MHz OCXO?  

You are asking the wrong questions and not giving the right specs ! You made a possible trivial answer from a complex question with no specs.

Comment: Well I guess it’s easy for you to hand out -1s since you have 121k reputation and years of experience as an engineer- very welcoming and inspiring to young people aspiring to be engineers like yourself. So if I can convey this to you in a way that you might understand, “ Please, speak as you might to a young child, or a golden retriever”. I’m not concerned about the specs (what precise ppm it is). This is a crude proof of concept. The driving waveform can be anything. I was using a DDS generated sinusoid but I may switch to a square wave because I don’t think I HAVE to use a sine wave.

Comment: I’m merely looking to stay locked onto the resonant frequency of the resonator - within 1hz is the goal. My question is how does one know if the phase comparator is accurate between the response signal coming through the ADC and the driving signal in the digital domain (I’m trying to avoid using an analog PD)? Maybe I am asking the wrong questions… if so, help me to understand why I’m asking the wrong question and I’ll amend my answer. I appreciate your time and thought put into this

Comment: It seems to me that you could just build a powered oscillator around your resonator and then just observe the frequency with a frequency counter. The oscillator will naturally track the resonant frequency of the resonator.

Comment: Andrew, you are the one asking for help.  People asking for help are the ones who have to go out of their way to be polite and accommodating.  No one is required to help you.  That having been said: in all of this it is *STILL* not clear what you are trying to actually accomplish.  Resonators are generally part of a larger system and the fact that you are refusing to explain the larger system is frustrating to the people trying to help you.

Comment: Andrew, actually no. Politeness goes both ways. I am not forcing them to help me; they chose to do so which I'm grateful for but doesn't entitle them to different standards of behavior or "speech". As to the Pierce oscillator, I know this topology relies on an inverter and thus an op amp. Will Op Amps work into 6Mhz? How about 50Mhz? I can see digikey has op amps that have a "gain bandwidth product" up to 800Ghz. If this is true, this may work to stay locked onto resonance but I had hoped to have no circuitry external to the FPGA but perhaps this isn't a realistic goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need a PLL, rather you need a series and parallel oscillator and, you must choose which mode is preferable.**

It could also be an Injection Locked Loop which could be an offset biased and forced oscillation with mutual coupling, and is a [common phenomena of nature.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-_VPRCtiUg)

Your resonant frequency will change with every environmental variable from temperature, pressure, vibration, shock, and equivalent parasitic capacitance and equivalent inductance ESL.

When you make an oscillator, you can easily measure f, and tune it with a known C. It can be pulled or drift within  in the BW determined by Q and possible a harmonic with a known capacitance and gain to satisfy the **Barkhausen criterion of >=1 loop gain at 0 Deg.**

[image]

The [above is a simulation](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%203243.9346728336795%0Al%20784%20496%20832%20496%200%201%20-0.010791244163668997%0Ac%20784%20528%20896%20528%200%202.7e-7%200%0Ac%20896%20496%20832%20496%200%202.7000000000000004e-8%200%0Aw%20608%20496%20688%20496%200%0Aw%20896%20496%20944%20496%200%0Ar%20784%20496%20752%20496%200%200.1%0Ag%20944%20496%20944%20512%200%0A170%20560%20496%20512%20496%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AO%20688%20496%20688%20464%200%0Aw%20784%20496%20784%20528%200%0Aw%20896%20496%20896%20528%200%0Ar%20560%20496%20608%20496%200%2010000%0Aw%20688%20496%20752%20496%200%0A) of the impedance ratio of a 1kHz resonator similar to any Piezo or Xtal resonators.  fs= 969 Hz, fp= 1.02 kHz  . By adding reactance, one could tune the frequency to exactly 1.000 kHz, if you wanted or make it into an oscillator.

- Higher voltage low current, or high current low voltage where current is proportional to force like ultrasonic exciters.
- Series mode is in phase or 0 deg. and parallel mode is anti-phase or 180 deg., and thus requires an inverter to oscillate with negative feedback for DC as well to self-bias.
- Series mode requires a low source impedance to drive it.
- The Qs in series mode is \$Q_s= \dfrac{X_{(\omega_0)}}{R~~~~~}= \dfrac{\omega_0 L}{R} =  \dfrac{1}{\omega_0 RC}\$
- The Qp in parallel mode is the inverse, \$Q_p=\dfrac{R~~~~}{X_{(\omega_{_0)}}}=\dfrac{R}{\omega_0 L} =  {\omega_0 RC}\$
- also damping factor \$\zeta=\dfrac{1}{2Q}\$

***[Q is relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_factor) to all harmonic and oscillatory behaviours from an electron to a gyrotron to a piezo crystal to a structural resonance to an RF induction heater***.

Q is also defined by the impedance ratios to determine the resonant frequency  to the half-power full bandwidth, BW ratio.

How you choose to oscillate your high Q resonant material depends on your **expectations** and assumptions or to be defined, (TBD) **"SPECS"**

i.e. Define your specs then a simple solution is possible.

But you don't need a complex PLL, although that is possible,  if you have a signal from the resonating signal and a mixer that shifts the phase by 90 deg or 180 deg or 360 deg, by design.

The simplest solution for a sinusoidal Hartley Oscillator using a 6 MHz Series Xtal is [as follows](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsCmC0CM8QHYB0A2eBOZAOS6kyATDmEVJFFBDAvAFABOIAzJMSACy5scjxivCIjBjmbMFwFDJ04sWkQFYsBK7x0A5Fo1aFSmeIDufTj26buwhqfacDl-YvAMA8k4FdpXdNPje4K4ASp4WegJaEBBctEHRqJAMAOaejhGK0a4ALmYyvBGCwgIgsJCoyFiQuIqQkGDIPOispWCoOArVvqzE6I1gSPCqIAAm0ABmAIYArgA22bZy+XlFrnb8jqxSII5qAMYrsvbaUQKJcEOt7STEXc29-UhtYowHx-A6ebtndJdtH35WKxcFgsIQ6lwdJxngNFoVPu9PmpTPDdFYAkoJKtVlt-LIROIDqtNttvvALgSMGBMtS8MhIPBcI1wKgXgwNJxsbJiS4ngAdADOyAuxEF9FQuDAYPQWE0XF69RIgph-IF5IQrEFgg4qEUXDBWHwxE0WGVrIG4DNYmQUtBdvt9sgVqkzRtihBREqPS4ystAvq6is4XRgiCgnEAAdPADuH4TiVMbEWvqtGCQOheegspAAPo9HNgHPayBcHPEVCIZq07AkG300swgYFosMAD2OzY0O47GkVGe2qCDjYbZAvB63AEPeIyGo-xKjCAA).  If you need lower harmonic content or higher voltage or lower impedance, then you need a spec. for V, Z, f, tolerances, bias etc.

**But if you only need it  to oscillate, this is all you need.**

[image]

Changing the 150 pF ratios can amplify the signal to 10Vpp.
I chose std values for a 6 MHz series Xtal.

Comment: I will go over your answer tomorrow. You originally said I need a transfer function - if this is true then I can make one using Simulink and experimental data. I don’t entirely understand your answer at first glance. Thanks for your time

Comment: It all depends what you want out of this Xtal, Sine square VCXO, TCVXO, PLL VCXO DTXO etc

Comment: You needed to define both input and output characteristics.

Comment: Fundamentally, I want to use this as a sensor to tell me something like what the ambient temperature is or what mass is on the resonator itself based on a shift in resonant frequency (but remained locked onto the ever changing resonance). As to what method is best to do that, I’m not sure. All I know is that amplitude response is insufficient so I’m using phase now (I need a fully fledged vector network analyzer). I don’t care what the shape of the output or driving signal is as long as it works to stay on resonance. I’m sorry for my shallow understanding. I’ll look over your answer right now

Comment: Frequency and pressure voltage sensitivity will be greatest with smallest  load capacitance which shifts frequency up.  Measure frequency with a stable reference then mixing it is the best method if your sensing is linear or as sensitive as you expect.

Comment: I know that piezoelectric accelerometers measure acceleration by charge amplifiers and that crystals are sensitive to vibration and shock, both elastic and plastic (damage) even using ruggedized SC-type Xtals in OCXO's from lots of personal testing.   So It depends if you want stable elastic response to motional capacitance or Xtal lattice or plastic damage response.    I used a simple PLL mixer and LPF to compare stable and unstable crystal oscillators to measure the stability vs shock on each axis, vibration and centripetal acceleration in each axis.  So it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: No need for fancy test equipment or digital PLL to do any of this.   Just a TI counter or frequency counter or a DSO trace .  If using sine source then the mixer output is a sine response., If using square waves then you get a linear triangle error frequency or slope in ppm.  This is also useful for Doppler sensing.

Comment: two identical oscillators will shift in frequency under any stress. What are you trying to measure or expect?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to see a large signal amplification in your resonator, you need to load it so that its unloaded Q is dominating the loaded Q. That means that losses in the resonator dominate losses in the drive and sense impedances.

You either need to drive and sense from short circuits, or from open circuits. Which is easier to do will depend on the impedance level, Q and frequency of your resonator, which you haven't disclosed. That's for an LC resonator where you get the choice of configuring it in series or parallel. For a mechanical resonator, you may be stuck with just one choice.

If you choose short circuits, then a voltage output DDS is easy. You'd sense the current at the ADC with either a virtual ground amplifier, or a very small resistor to ground that you sense the voltage across. If you choose open circuits, then a high impedance buffer for the ADC is easy, and you'd need to current drive from your DDS, either making a high impedance active current drive like a Howland, or an open collector, or simply a high value resistor in series with a voltage source.

When a resonator is in resonance, the voltage across and current through are in phase.

So now the PLL is straightforward. Pick a drive frequency. Measure the current phase with respect to drive phase. Adjust the drive frequency up or down, rinse and repeat until you get zero phase.

The response to a change in frequency will be slow, and the higher the Q of the device, the slower it will be. This places an unavoidable lowpass filter in the loop. For loop stability, you need to arrange for the loop bandwidth to be somewhat less than this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyMqqT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What you call it PID is actually a compensator, PI like. You do measure voltage and current and compare their phases.

But this circuit would be too complex, you could simplify it by making a zero cross detectors for voltage and current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN1BhP.png)</sup>

In All Digital PLL (ADPLL) the phase detector measures pulses, not analog values. It's much simpler and robust than using ADC. Further you can add a digital lag to compensate the voltage/current measurement phase difference

EDIT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faiF2T.png)</sup>

Note, that you don't even need a DDS and the analog amplifier for resonant circuit, a H-bridge is enough. You can find similar implementations in inductive heating furnaces, resonant Tesla coil drivers. They all have one issue, at the light load it would blow off due to accumulating energy. So there are many techniques to avoid this by skipping some periods or modulating the output with Enhanced Pulse-Density-Modulation ([EPDM](https://oshwhub.com/attachments/2020/6/D8VRJJLjfbH5hbNekBvRVfriq2qsbL3cZqyiYXBb.pdf)).

Comment: Can you not find a simpler solution?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 The solution is based on OPs wishes, Complex wishes, complex solutions. But those are used in large induction heating furnaces.

Comment: I have helped others make a large induction furnace with a simple oscillator and tuned filter to select the fundamental.

Comment: You have made assumptions not mentioned , regarding mode of operation and phase assumptions for max current or max voltage or matched power transfer with conjugate matching without any reference.

Comment: If you consider the OP's question might be XY, then you can consider better solutions.